# How to return a proper Promise with TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, es6-promise

So I am learning Angular 2 with typescript.

I am reaching a point to write a mocking service which (I believe) should return a Promise if the service get the Object Successfully and Return an Error if anything happens.

I have tried following code but looks like it is not a write syntax for typescript.

Updated the CODE:

```
saveMyClass(updatedMyClass: MyClass){
        //saving MyClass using http service
        //return the saved MyClass or error
        var savedMyClass : MyClass = someLogicThatReturnsTheSavedObject(updatedMyClass);
        if(isSomeCondition)
            return Promise.reject(new Error('No reason but to reject'));
        else
            return new Promise<MyClass>(resolve => {setTimeout( ()=>resolve(savedMyClass),1500  )}  );
    }
```

But to my surprise, the typescript complained that "No best common type exists among return expressions".

What should be the right code? So that I could use on my component to consume if proper MyClass is returned and reflect error if any exists from service.

Thanks

Comment: Don't tag javascript with typescript! Typescript is not pure javascript

Comment: have u tried this ? https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts

Comment: assuming saveMyClass is a function try this 
function saveMyClass(updatedMyClass: MyClass): any {....code here....}

Answer (score 94, accepted):

It is considered a good practice to embed the whole function body inside the `Promise` constructor, so should any error happen, it would be converted to a rejection. In this case it solves your problem too I believe.

```
saveMyClass(updatedMyClass: MyClass) {
    return new Promise<Package>((resolve, reject) => {
        //saving MyClass using http service
        //return the saved MyClass or error
        var savedPackage : Package = updatedPackage;
        if (isSomeCondition) {
            throw new Error('No reason but to reject');
        }

        setTimeout( () => {
            resolve(savedPackage);
        }, 1500);
    });
}
```

Comment: setTimeout should never be used to control things like this, but since typescript and javascript is broken fundamentally, you might as well do it, regardless of how absurd it is.

Comment: @CarComp this code is the direct answer to OPs question without any unnecessary modification.

Comment: JavaScript is indeed fundamentally broken in many places, but not the async part. Async in javascript is reasonably good and straightforward compared to other languages.